# Cross-Origin xmlhttprequest.response

Tags: javascript, security, cors, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am building a real time monitoring page that 
sends xmlhttprequest and then validate response code. 
the problem is that Cross-Origin is blocking the load and the status is always 0.

Is there a way to get the response code ( no need for content ) and bypass this header Cross-Origin ?

Comment: That is security in the nutshell, just like how hackers would love to get around it too so they can make requests to your bank account, email, etc.

Comment: If it is local development, set up your browser to ignore it.

Comment: if you dont need content just use a mock

Answer (score -1):

install node.js or phantomjs or nightmare to your compurter and run it within your compurter. I will work.